# Problem in creating a new column using for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have to create a new column 'Action' in a dataframe whose values are :
1 if the next day's Close Price is greater than the present day's
-1 if the next day's Close Price is less than the present day's
that is,
Action[i] = 1 if Close Price[i+1]>Close Price[i]
Action[i] = -1 if Close Price[i+1]

I have used the following code:

```
dt =  pd.read_csv("C:\Subhro\ML_Internship\HDFC_Test.csv", sep=',',header=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(dt)

for i in df.index:
   if(df['Close Price'][i+1]>df['Close Price'][i]):
       df['Action'][i]=1
   elif(df['Close Price'][i+1]<df['Close Price'][i]):
       df['Action'][i]=-1
```

print(df)
 But I am getting an error :
KeyError: 'Action'
in line:
df['Action'][i]=1

Please help me out

Comment: Please share a small example of the current dataframe.

Comment: Avoid `loops` as much you can for pandas. You may want this `>>> df["Action"] = np.where(df["Close Price"].shift(-1) > df["Close Price"], 1,
-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the key error because you don't have a column called `action`. Any of the following before the loop will resolve the error:

```
df['Action'] = 0
```

or

```
df['Action'] = np.nan
```

However, you will get warnings because of the way you are assigning the cell values. [(See here)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

It is recommended that you instead use e.g.

```
df.loc[i, "Action"] = 1
```

Note that with this method, you won't even need to create an empty "Action" column before the loop.

Comment: I did it.. But now getting KeyError = 481

Comment: You are getting that on this: `df['Close Price'][i+1]` because your index is probably from 0 to 480 and you are asking the program to check 481. 
Play around with `df["Close Price"].shift(-1) > df["Close Price"]` instead.

Comment: You can use `df["Action"] = np.where(df["Close Price"].shift(-1) > df["Close Price"], 1, -1)` and avoid the loop altogether, but I wanted to also address why you are getting these errors.